# VSCode after installing python showing error in selecting interpreter

Tags: python

"No Python interpreter is selected. You need to select a Python interpreter to enable features such as IntelliSense, linting, and debugging."

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctrl+shift+P` and then search for "Python: Select interpreter".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, go to settings and search for `Python: Default Interpreter Path` there type the same path as the path showed to you when you click on `Select Interpreter` and choose your preferred interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto Applications folder and open Python Launcher
2. Copy the path from Interpreter field [Python Launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyLbt.png)
3. Open vsCode and use Ctrl+Shift+p and type "select interpreter in Python Launcher"
   [Enter select interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdcll.png)
4. Select the prompted option and paste the above copied path here
   [Paste path here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qJch.png)
5. Run the app